# VSCode selection border color

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I am tweaking a color theme in vscode. I would like to be able to have the selection have a background color and a separate border color.

I am unable to achieve this.

editor.selectionBorder - does nothing
editor.selectionHighlightBorder - highlight other instances of variables, but does not apply to the selection.

Is there any other border options I am missing?

Comment: "editor.selectionBackground": "#ff0000",  works for the current selection but I think you are right in finding no setting for coloring the border of the current selection oddly.

Comment: There's no `editor.selectionBorder` option, at least [no yet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference). Here's the relevant issues on GitHub: [`#45292`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45292) and [`#30793`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30793)

Comment: You have to use extension.

Comment: IronGeek. Yours is the best answer. If you add it as the answer, you will get the bounty.....act fast.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71007826/4984618

Answer (score 2):

Vscode does not include border change config in settings.(06 Nov 2018).
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors

Vscode border style issues have been merged here. You may vote for future implementation.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46804#issuecomment-377000600

> Preferences > Settings > ... menu > open settings.json > User settings

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations":{
        "editor.selectionBackground" : "#642F4D", 
        "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ffd700" // <tag></tag> or {}
        ... need border implementation for selection
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: He's looking for the border color.  How is this an answer?

Comment: @Mark, the border option is not implemented yet. You can use extension or you can update vs code source in github to implement it.

Comment: @John what do you mean by "use extension"? is there an existing extension that allows you to set the border of the current selection?

Comment: @john the link that you mentioned https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46804#issuecomment-377000600 appears to be marked as Closed. Also closed is github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45292.