# How to change the selected text background highlight color in vscode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the selected text background highlight color in the vscode *code* editor.

The default seem to be some kind of *light-blue* for the selected word, and some kind of *gray* for the other words with same text.

[image]

**How do I change the background color of these selected items?**

For example, I would like the gray shade to be `Goldenrod` (`#FFDAA520`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it after a lot of trial & error:

```json
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        //"editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#DAA520",
        //"editor.findRangeHighlightBackground": "#DAA520",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#DAA520",
        //"editor.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#DAA520",
        //"editor.findMatchBackground": "#DAA520",
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel I'm going blind, now I can find things! I'm doing: "editor.findMatchBorder": "#ff0000", "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#ffd700", "editor.selectionBackground": "#642F4D", "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#daa52073".